# How to start application(path with space) using QProcess on mac OSX?

Tags: macos, space, qprocess

It goes well when using QProcess to start a program if its path without space.
eg:

```
QProcess app;
app.startDetached("open /Users/test/Desktop/MyTest/Hello.app");
```

But, it doesn't work if the program path containing spaces.
eg:

```
QProcess app;
app.startDetached("open /Users/test/Desktop/My Test/Hello.app");
```

Someone can help me and tell me how to start a program with space in its path?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use quotes in the string for the path:-

```
app.startDetached("open \"/Users/test/Desktop/My Test/Hello.app\"");
```

Without the quotes, the space will suggest the next part of the path as a 2nd parameter passed to the call to open.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I tried and got failure with message: The file /Users/test/Desktop/My Test/Hello.app does not exist. The path to app is correct. Is there something limited with "open"?

Comment: Try using it with the full path to the executable in the bundle, which would be "/Users/test/Desktop/My Test/Hello.app/Contents/Mac OS/hello"

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. I tried your first advice(using quotes) again and found it's correct. It's my fault when testing. And your second method which directly path to binary file is OK, but I prefer to the first one.

Comment: proc->start("deepin-image-viewer \"" + path+"\"");